# How to fix a frozen activity due to a thread inside a recycler adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created an activity where there is a recycler view that is supposed to show the last games played. It loads the data but when i want to go back to the previous activity the app freezes.

For what I have tried I believe the problem is the thread I use inside the onBindViewHolder method of the adapter, since if i delete the thread and the content inside it the app doesn't freeze.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Match match = listMatches.get(position);
    final Holder holder = (Holder) viewHolder;
    holder.score.setText(match.getKills() + "/" + match.getDeaths() + "/" + match.getAssists());
    holder.queue.setText(getQueueName(match.getQueue()));


    try {
        final String imageUrl = getChampImg(match.getChampId());
        final String imageSum1Url = getSumImg(match.getSummoner1());
        final String imageSum2Url = getSumImg(match.getSummoner2());
        final String imageObj1Url = getObjImg(match.getItem1());
        final String imageObj2Url = getObjImg(match.getItem2());
        final String imageObj3Url = getObjImg(match.getItem3());
        final String imageObj4Url = getObjImg(match.getItem4());
        final String imageObj5Url = getObjImg(match.getItem5());
        final String imageObj6Url = getObjImg(match.getItem6());
        final boolean win = match.getMatchResult();

        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        if (win == true) {
                            holder.background.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBackground));
                        } else {
                            holder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }

                        //CHAMP IMAGE
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
                        holder.imageChamp.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        //SUMS
                        Bitmap bitmapSum1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageSum1Url).getContent());
                        holder.sum1.setImageBitmap(bitmapSum1);
                        Bitmap bitmapSum2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageSum2Url).getContent());
                        holder.sum2.setImageBitmap(bitmapSum2);
                        //ITEMS
                        if (imageObj1Url.length() > 1) {
                            Bitmap bitmapObj1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageObj1Url).getContent());
                            holder.item1.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj1);
                        }
                        if (imageObj2Url.length() > 1) {
                            Bitmap bitmapObj2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageObj2Url).getContent());
                            holder.item2.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj2);
                        }
                        if (imageObj3Url.length() > 1) {
                            Bitmap bitmapObj3 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageObj3Url).getContent());
                            holder.item3.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj3);
                        }
                        if (imageObj4Url.length() > 1) {
                            Bitmap bitmapObj4 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageObj4Url).getContent());
                            holder.item4.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj4);
                        }
                        if (imageObj5Url.length() > 1) {
                            Bitmap bitmapObj5 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageObj5Url).getContent());
                            holder.item5.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj5);
                        }
                        if (imageObj6Url.length() > 1) {
                            Bitmap bitmapObj6 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageObj6Url).getContent());
                            holder.item6.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj6);
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: use glide or Picasso lib to load images for an easy solution as for now

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Thanks @AkarshM glide solved the problem